# tearDown(): clean up with closures

Tags: python, unit-testing, closures

I am not happy with the static way `TestCase.tearDown()` works.

Sometimes I create stuff during an unittest which I want to be cleaned up later, and I don't know in advance what needs to be cleaned up later.

Is it possible to add closures to a `tear_down_list` which get executed in `tearDown()`?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(Foo, self).setUp()
        self.tear_down_list = []
    def tearDown(self):
        super(Foo, self).tearDown()
        for cb in self.tear_down_list:
            cb() # prints 5
    def foo(self):
        # ...
        foo = 5
        def bar():
            print(foo)
        self.tear_down_list.append(bar)
        # ...
```